# Installing r-text in R gives error Failed to build tokenizers on MAC M1 and M2 chip

Tags: r, r-text

When running:

```
textrpp_install()
```

this error is thrown:

```
Failed to build tokenizers
ERROR: Could not build wheels for tokenizers, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved it by opening the terminal in MAC OS to run:

```
curl --proto '=https' --tlsv1.2 -sSf https://sh.rustup.rs | sh
```

(I also restarted R and Rstudio)